# Monopoly: check for double only if player lands naturally

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Monopoly when a player lands on Chance or Community chest, a card is drawn that might instruct a player to advance to a different location, in such a case the player's turn is over even if he rolled a double. It is this feature I am trying to incorporate in my code. [Here is a spreadsheet plan of my code.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2MVg38svpHAv1pmj_bPIzcwQo9MT13TzwK8JEWydSM/edit?usp=sharing)

The problem is at what level should I put `checkDouble`. I want to check for doubles if the player landed there by roll of dice, and NOT when the player is moved by a card.

At the moment when a player clicks buy, `checkDouble` already ran and so did `changeTurn`, so the wrong player gets assigned to the purchased property.

**I have not included all my code which is 455 lines of code. I hope that I have provided enough code.**

```
function gameEngine(){
    clearContent();
    rollDice();
    drawDice(dice1, dice2);
    processDice(); 
    updatePos();    
    movePiece();
    checkPurchasable();
    checkDouble();// this is a problem, because by the time the player clicks the buy button, checkDouble has run and hence changeTurn.
}

function checkPurchasable(){
    if (getPurchasable()) {
        checkForsale();
    } else {
        nonPurchasable();
    }
}

function checkForsale() {
    if (getOwner() == "unowned") {
        toggleButtons();
        if ($(".action-card").is(":visible")) {
        $(".action-card").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(".deed-card").toggle();   
        });
        } else {
        $(".deed-card").toggle();   
        }

        switch (true) {
        case (getType() == "city"):
                showDeedCard();
                break;
            case (getType() == "airport"):
                showAirportCard();
                break;
            case (getType() == "utility"):
                showUtilityCard();
                break;
        }   
    } else {
        payRent();
    }
}

function nonPurchasable() {
    switch(true) {
        case (getType() == "chest"):
            drawCard(player, chest, "Community Chest");
            break;
        case (getType() == "tax"):
            updateBalance(getTax()*-1,player);
            break;
        case (getType() == "chance"):
            drawCard(player, chance, "Chance");
            break;
        case (getType() == "corner"):
            break;
    }
}

function Buy() {
    $(".deed-card").slideToggle();
    toggleButtons();
    assignOwner();
    updateBalance(getPrice()*-1,player);
    var x = getTitle();
    var xx = x.substring(0,3);
    var res = xx.toUpperCase();
    if (getType() != "city") {
        $("#assets"+player).append('<span class="black">' + res + '</span>');
    } else {
        showPrice();
        var set = positions[pos].set;
        $("#assets"+player).append('<span class="' + set + '">' + res + '</span>');
    }
}

function drawCard(player, deck, title) {
    var card = deck.shift();
    flipCard(card.instruction, title);
    card.act(player);
    deck.push(card);
}

function assignOwner() {
    positions[pos].owner = player;
}

function changeTurn() {
    player = 1 - player;
}

function checkDouble() {
    if (isDouble) {
        dblRolls++;
    } else {
        dblRolls = 0;
        changeTurn();
    }
}

function AbsMoveCard(instruction, destination) {
    this.instruction = instruction;
    this.destination = destination;
}

AbsMoveCard.prototype.act = function(player) {
    pos = this.destination;
    if (pos == 0 || pos<players[player].pos) {
        updateBalance(200, player);
    }
    isDouble = false;
    updatePos();
    movePiece();
    checkPurchasable();
};

function RelMoveCard(instruction, distance) {
    this.instruction = instruction;
    this.distance = distance;
}

RelMoveCard.prototype.act = function(player) {
    alert("Moving relative.");
    pos -= this.distance;
    isDouble = false;
    updatePos();
    movePiece();
    checkPurchasable();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If when the dice are rolled you set a flag for `rolledDoubles` you can clear that flag when you follow `pickcard` into `movement`. For all other paths at the terminal node check the flag `rolledDoubles` and if it is set call a new 'letPlayerKnowTheyCanRollAgain' which calls `rollDice`.

Your spreadsheet was helpful in visualizing the various choices at each point. I'm rusty on the rules for Monopoly.

Comment: I already have a variable `isDouble` in my `rollDice` function which generates 2 random dice rolls. `checkDouble` uses that variable later on to determine whether to `changeTurn` or not. I set that variable to false when the player is moved by a card. So it will be checkPurchasable --> pickCard --> movement --> checkPurchasble (but now isDouble is set to false.) --> checkDouble (since isDouble is false, changeTurn runs.)

Comment: Does `changeTurn` have checks to make sure that all user input has completed, or are you using callbacks to prevent changeTurn being called until the user has exhausted their options? For instance does `showPurchaseCard` use a callback function?

Comment: No it doesn't. `changeTurn` simply toggles between 1 and 0. I don't know what callbacks are, I will have to read on that. `ShowPurchaseCard` also doesn't use callback function.

Comment: Where you call 'fadeOut' already uses a callback. The `'slow'` is a parameter to fadeOut, but the `function() {$(".deed-card").toggle();});` is the callback because it gets executed when `fadeout` is finished. If you call for the display of a choice to the user you can implement a callback to continue with your code when they make their choice. This will prevent their choice from taking place after you've switched users.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was called a call back. I just thought it was just an additional parameter that would be called when the fadeOut is completed. This might solve the problem, at the moment `showPurchaseCard` prompts the player with a choice of buying or auctioning, but the code doesn't wait for the player to make the choice, and continues with `checkDouble`, by the time the player makes the choice, the turn has already been changed and the wrong player gets assigned with the purchased property. How would I use callback to solve that problem?

Comment: If `showPurchaseCard` has a dialog the dialog buttons click action could call `checkDouble`. Alternatively see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691762/how-to-add-a-callback-to-a-function-in-javacript