# How to create my own alert function with callback?

Tags: javascript

I have a Alert function defined as follow:

```
this.Alert = function(stitle, message) {
    var myself = this;

    if(window.alertDiv == undefined) {
        window.alertDiv = $('<div></div>');
        window.alertDiv.dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: stitle,
            height:300,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    window.alertDiv.dialog('option','title', stitle);

    if(!window.alertDiv.dialog('isOpen')) {
        window.alertDiv.dialog('open');
        window.alertDiv.html(message);
    } else {
        window.alertDiv.html(window.alertDiv.html() + '<div style="text-align:center;">----------</div><br /><br />' + message);
        window.alertDiv.css('height','300px');
    }
  }
```

Now I need create another Alert function with the same definition but with a callback. Does anybody how do I create the second Alert function by calling the current one while adding callback?

Comment: Um. Just have another parameter and pass your own function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a callback to a function in javacript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691762/how-to-add-a-callback-to-a-function-in-javacript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept a callback as a parameter, then execute said callback when you intend for it to be executed.

```
this.Alert = function(stitle, message, callback) {
```

and then:

```
window.alertDiv.dialog({
    modal: true,
    close: callback,
```

Comment: Is it possible to create the second alert function by calling the first one while adding callback?

Comment: Why not just have one that has an ***optional*** callback? (which is what my answer creates)