# How to assiciate a specific callback to an existing javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I want to attach a callback method to a javascript function in order to be called after its execution

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a callback to a function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691762/how-to-add-a-callback-to-a-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When you can't avoid doing this (which is usually best), the usual way to do it is to *wrap* the function in another function:

```js
function f(msg) {
    console.log("The message is: " + msg);
}

f("Before being wrapped");

console.log("Now wrapping the function");

// Then wrapping it
var originalF = f;
f = function() {
    var returnValue;
    console.log("This is before the original function");
    returnValue = originalF.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("This is after the original function");
    return returnValue;
};

f("After being wrapped");
```

Note the use of `Function#apply` to ensure that we call the original function with the same `this` value we were called with and all of the original arguments. Then we keep the return value and return it when we're done.

Of course, if the original function started an *asynchronous* task, we've only wrapped the original function, not the code triggered when the task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine the function. You can do this with an IIFE.

```
funcname = (function(oldfunc, callback) {
    return function() {
        var value = oldfunc.apply(this, arguments);
        callback();
        return value;
    })(funcname, callback);
);
```